# Pagination Not Working on /tags/<tag-name>/media/recent search

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I was trying to get a bunch of posts from a specific tag, but I am not able to get any results after the first request. This is the pagination object I get back on the first request:

```
{"pagination":
   {"next_min_id":"AQDp4XVApTQIiQaUWX1B2y0trzhasQ4prDMOCbiUpN_2zw4nbO5we0F5G3WMMLIxWaUcgji0r4BLkJoNiWZKy51QDuvERVsYu6qHjU0YPROFag",
    "deprecation_warning":"next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead",
    "min_tag_id":"AQDp4XVApTQIiQaUWX1B2y0trzhasQ4prDMOCbiUpN_2zw4nbO5we0F5G3WMMLIxWaUcgji0r4BLkJoNiWZKy51QDuvERVsYu6qHjU0YPROFag"}
```

So I add `min_tag_id` to my next request. It returns a 200 response code, but an empty data array. I tried a popular tag (the above results is from `/tags/cats/media/recent`). But the same response as each time; a handful of results on first request, empty array when using the returned `min_tag_id`.

**UPDATE**

Just tried the love tag, and it returns 0 results for me? (200 response code)

https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/love/media/recent/?access_token=YOUR_TOKEN

The response for `#love`

```
{"pagination": 
   {"deprecation_warning": "next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead"}, 
   "meta": {"code": 200}, "data": []}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you are not in sandbox mode? (In sandbox mode you can only get 20 posts in API response)

For pagination, add `&max_tag_id={{next_max_tag_id value}}` in the API URL param, this will get you next 20 posts.

Better way is to just use the `next_url` to make API call, this has the correct pagination param already added to API endpoint.

Comment: It started working without any changes, but your suggestion helps. Weird...